# Template specialization within class definition

Tags: c++, templates

I wonder whether it is possible to put the whole code of such a class inside the class (kind of as in Java). I'm doing this for some piece of code, instead of having to search for each function, I'd rather have the whole class on a single sheet of paper (yes, I do print them, I tend to like paper these days).

```
#include <iostream>

template <class V> class A {
public:
    A();
};

template <class V> A<V>::A() {
    std::cout<<"Generic"<<std::endl;
}

template <> A<bool>::A() {
    std::cout<<"bool"<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A<int> a;
    A<bool> b;
}
```

Now is it possible to get something along those lines ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <class V> class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout<<"Generic"<<std::endl;
    };
    /* somethig specifying specialization for bool */ A() {
        std::cout<<"bool"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A<int> a;
    A<bool> b;
}
```

Is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have everything in a single class definition without specializations, using `std::enable_if` to choose the appropriate constructor like this:

```
template <bool C, typename T = void>
using only_if = typename std::enable_if <C, T>::type;

template <typename A, typename B>
using eq = typename std::is_same <A, B>::type;

template <class V> class A {
public:
    template <typename D = int, only_if <!eq <V, bool>{}, D> = 0>
    A() { std::cout<<"Generic"<<std::endl; };

    template <typename D = int, only_if <eq <V, bool>{}, D> = 0>
    A() { std::cout<<"bool"<<std::endl; }
};
```

where template aliases `only_if` and `eq` are just for brevity.

Template parameter `D` is dummy. Usually we apply `enable_if` on a template parameter, a function argument, or a return type. A non-template default constructor is a unique exception having nothing of the above, hence the dummy.

This approach is maybe an overkill for this simple example, where a template specialization may be simpler. But a class of 30 lines of code that needs a specialization like that for just one constructor will be definitely simpler this way rather than duplicating all code for the entire class specialization. One may argue that in this case the code may be refactored using a base class that contains only what needs to be specialized. However:

- There are also cases where you don't want to choose between two constructor versions, but only to enable or disable a single version according to a type predicate, e.g. whether a type is `std::default_constructible` or not.
- Or, you may need to decide whether a constructor is declared `explicit` or not, again depending on a type predicate (so, provide an explicit and a non-explicit version).

In such cases, `enable_if` is very convenient.

[Check here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/tuple/store/tuple.hpp) an example of a very generic tuple implementation with five constructors, all using `enable_if`, and one (the default) using a dummy template parameter. The remaining four are for the combinations of explicit vs. non-explicit and element-list vs other-tuple.

Comment: Technically, this one is the most correct answer, although minus one for code readability :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is completely possible though the specialization must be done in other template.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class V> class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout<<"Generic"<<std::endl;
    };
 };

template <> class A<bool>
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Bool specialization" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A<int> a;
    A<bool> b;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this is still several "units", but it is indeed better that what I had initially in mind.