# Is it possible to set different access modifiers to a class member template specializations (and a class template member ones)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, access-modifiers

1. Is it possible to set different access modifiers to a class member template specializations? Example of code (does not compile):

   ```
   class SimpleClass
   {   
   public:
       template <typename T>
       void Method();
       template <>
       void Method<char>();
   protected:
       template <>
       void Method<int>();
   protected:
       template <>
       void Method<float>();
   };
   ```

   - Subquestion: is it possible to set different access modifiers to template constructor specializations of a class? Example of code (does not compile):

     ```
     class SimpleClass
     {
     public:
         template <typename T>
     SimpleClass(T);
         template <>
         SimpleClass<char>(char);
     protected:
         template <>
         SimpleClass<int>(int);
     private:
         template <>
         SimpleClass<float>(float);
     };
     ```
2. Is it possible to set different access modifiers to a class template member specializations? Example of code (does not compile):

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class ClassTemplate
   {   
   public:
       void Method();
       template <>
       void Method<char>();
   protected:
       template <>
       void Method<int>();
   protected:
       template <>
       void Method<float>();
   };
   ```

   - Subquestion: is it possible to set different access modifiers to constructor specializations of a class template? Example of code (does not compile):

     ```
     template <typename T>
     class ClassTemplate
     {
     public:
         ClassTemplate(T);
         template <>
         ClassTemplate<char>(char);
     protected:
         template <>
         ClassTemplate<int>(int);
     private:
         template <>
         ClassTemplate<float>(float);
     };
     ```

**To be more specific:** in **1)** I'm looking for a C++03 workaround for such C++11 code:

```
class SimpleClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    SimpleClass(T);

    template <typename T>
    void Method();
};

template <>
SimpleClass::SimpleClass<char>(char);
template <>
SimpleClass::SimpleClass<int>(int) = delete;

template <>
void SimpleClass::Method<char>();
template <>
void SimpleClass::Method<int>() = delete;
```

In **2)** I'm looking for a C++03 workaround for the following C++11 code:

```
template <typename T>
class ClassTemplate
{
public:
    ClassTemplate(T);

    void Method();
};

template <>
ClassTemplate<char>::ClassTemplate(char);
template <>
ClassTemplate<int>::ClassTemplate(int) = delete;

template <>
void ClassTemplate<char>::Method();
template <>
void ClassTemplate<int>::Method() = delete;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following some discussion, here is a complete account of all cases including different access specifiers using the approach of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538105/2644390).

```
template <bool C, typename T = void>
using only_if = typename std::enable_if <C, T>::type;

template <typename A, typename B>
using eq = typename std::is_same <A, B>::type;

class SimpleClass1
{
public:
    template <typename T, only_if <!eq <T, int>{} && !eq <T, float>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass1() { }
protected:
    template <typename T, only_if <eq <T, int>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass1() { }
protected:
    template <typename T, only_if <eq <T, float>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass1() { }
};

class SimpleClass2
{
public:
    template <typename T, only_if <!eq <T, int>{} && !eq <T, float>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass2(T) { }
protected:
    template <typename T, only_if <eq <T, int>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass2(T) { }
private:
    template <typename T, only_if <eq <T, float>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass2(T) { }
};

template <typename T>
class ClassTemplate1
{
public:
    template <typename U, only_if <!eq <U, int>{} && !eq <U, float>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method() { }
protected:
    template <typename U, only_if <eq <U, int>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method() { }
protected:
    template <typename U, only_if <eq <U, float>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method() { }
};

template <typename T>
class ClassTemplate2
{
public:
    template <typename U, only_if <!eq <U, int>{} && !eq <U, float>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method(U) { }
protected:
    template <typename U, only_if <eq <U, int>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method(U) { }
protected:
    template <typename U, only_if <eq <U, float>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method(U) { }
};
```

I don't know where all this would be useful :-) Anyhow:

- I have been careful to make all constructor/method overloads mutually exclusive to avoid ambguities and problems with different access specifiers, which can be tricky. This makes it more difficult to generalize to more types. A template alias would help for the generic/default case (which is the complement of all others).
- However, this is not exactly equivalent to what you described in the question. These methods enforce strict type equality, so do not allow implicit conversions. You could try `std::is_convertible` instead but then you're opening the door to ambiguities.
- The entire code compiles as such but I didn't try to actually use the classes, so I don't know what might happen.
- I really don't know how one can use `SimpleClass1`: How can we possibly explicitly specify a template argument for a default constructor (since it cannot be deduced)?
- Looking at the code again, I think that `ClassTemplate` is not much different (or at all) from `SimpleClass`. `ClassTemplate1` cannot have a default template argument, because that would be ambiguous.

Comment: This whole question is a bit of an XY Problem, but +1 for solving it!

Comment: @SamCristall Oh, I didn't know this term, but now I know the hard way :-)

Comment: @SamCristall Yes, I think you are right about XY problem. :-)

Comment: `SimpleClass1` can not be used, you are right. That is why I used a constructor with one parameter in my question.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with SFINAE, but unfortunately we need `is_same` and `enable_if`.  *Fortunately*, neither of those require any C++11 language!  So we can just bring in their implementations for our own needs:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct is_same {
  static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename A>
struct is_same <A, A> {
  static const bool value = true;
};

template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

Next, we combine them using `enable_if` to "SFINAE delete" methods you don't want.  The template constructor/method needs a gimmick.  We need the first argument to be the type for argument deduction.  We add a second, dummy argument for the sole purpose of deleting the method if the type isn't one you support.  You can add overloads for more types if you need to.  For `Method()` we can apply the dummy argument again, and `T` will be given explicitly, so no need for any deduction:

```
class SimpleClassConstructor {
public:
  template <typename T>
  SimpleClassConstructor(T value, 
                         typename enable_if<is_same<T, char>::value, T>::type enabler = 0) {
  }
  template <typename T>
  void Method(typename enable_if<is_same<T, char>::value, T>::type enabler = 0) {
  }
};
```

For the template class, ~~we can use the exact same methodology, but we can use the result of `enable_if` directly since we don't need argument deduction.~~  To satisfy the requirements of specifically deleting methods, we can move the `enable_if` methodology to a template parameter.  This will let SFINAE delete the method softly (rather than disabling the entire class if the `enable_if` fails):

```
template <typename T>
class SimpleClassTemplate {
public:
  template <typename Enable = enable_if<is_same<T, char>::value, T>::type>
  SimpleClassTemplate(T value) {

  }
};
```

For a test, try these:

```
int main() {
  char a = 0;
  SimpleClassTemplate<char> A1(a); // OK
  SimpleClassConstructor A2(a); // OK

  A2.Method<char>(); // OK
  A2.Method<int>(); // compilation error!

  int b = 0;
  SimpleClassTemplate<int> B1(b); // compilaton error!
  SimpleClassConstructor B2(b); // compilation error!
}
```

Comment: There remains the case of no input parameters.

Comment: @iavr I don't follow -- could you be more specific?

Comment: If there is no input parameter to a constructor (default constructor) or method, you cannot have `enable_if` (or anything) inside parentheses. The question refers to the case of a template method with no parameters (where the template parameter needs to be explicitly specified by the caller).

Comment: @iavr I have that case, just not in my tests, I will add it.

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22538105/2644390) and the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22385754/2644390).

Comment: @iavr See my edit.  I've covered the template method with no parameters.

Comment: Hmmm... Nice, this is shorter than my solution (everything inside `template <...>`). But I am not sure this will work in the case of variadic parameters (having another parameter with default value after the variadic ones).

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is ok, but it does not allow the use of explicit instantiation: `template class SimpleClassTemplate<int>;`.

Comment: @Constructor See my new implementation that fixes that issue.

Comment: Oh, I think you did not need to remove your old variant, it was good. Now you got almost the exact @iavr's solution. But thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @Constructor The primary feature of my code is that it is C++03 compliant, which that solution is not (though not to say his couldn't easily be modified to be)

Comment: `enable_if`, `is_same` and other type traits were implemented long before C++11 approximately in a way you have shown in your answer, so the solution of @iavr can be considered to be C++03 compliant.

Comment: @Constructor I was actually referring to the `using` syntax, not the `type_traits` stuff

Comment: As I can see this syntax is used in @iavr's solution only for code reduction and carries no real logical load.

Answer (score 2):

For a default constructor or method with no input parameters, I think the answer to [Template specialization within class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22385754/2644390) suffices. It only uses `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`, which are easy to define.

For an one-parameter constructor or method, I think you can apply the same method, which is even easier here because there's already a (deduced) template parameter so you don't need a dummy one.

```
template <bool C, typename T = void>
using only_if = typename std::enable_if <C, T>::type;

template <typename A, typename B>
using eq = typename std::is_same <A, B>::type;

class SimpleClass {
public:
    template <typename T, only_if <!eq <T, int>{}, int> = 0>
    SimpleClass(T) { ... }

    template <typename T, only_if <!eq <T, int>{}, int> = 0>
    void Method(T) { ... }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you. One remark: you forgot `void` before `Method`. This solves 1), but not 2) as I understand. Am I right? And what about solving general problem?

Comment: Thanks, corrected. I think you have mixed the problems, because each of (1) and (2) contains two examples, which refer to different problems. I think I am clear that what is here refers to one (or more) parameters, and my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22385754/2644390) to no parameters. Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean a problem of a class template, not a class member template.

Comment: Oh, now I see. In (2) you have a class template. Well, my previous answer is such a case, only with no parameters. I think `template <only_if <!eq <T, int>{}, int> = 0> SimpleClass(T) { ... };` should be fine. Otherwise, add a dummy parameter: `template <typename D = T, only_if <!eq <D, int>{}, int> = 0> SimpleClass(T) { ... };`.

Comment: Good. The second solution is better because it allows the use of explicit instantiation: `template class SimpleClass<int>;`. Can I ask a silly question? Why do you add a semicolon after the method definition?

Comment: @Constructor Sorry no reason, so many typos... :-) I'm correcting the answer now.

Comment: That's all right, it was only a question. :-) But what about solution of a general problem - member specializations with different access specifiers?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was only an attempt to simulate what was below "To be more specific". If you do need different access specifiers, I am not sure, I have to try.

Comment: I have only theoretical interest, don't worry so much. :-)

Comment: You got me stuck, so see my new answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Template Specialization":

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
    void foo();
    void bar();
};

template <>
struct S<int> {
    void foo();
};



int main()
{
    S<char> sc;
    sc.foo();
    sc.bar();

    S<int> si;
    si.foo();
    si.bar(); // compile error: 'bar' : is not a member of 'S<int>'

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use specializations of class template members (and class member templates), not a whole class template.