# How to NOT overload the std::map::at member function in the case where the two template types are the same?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a here a bidirectional map. I make it form 0. I defined member functions like `insert` `count` `size` and others and of course a function `at` which returns a reference to the mapped value of the element identified with the given key. Until type A is not the same with type B everything works fine, but when type A is the same with type B i get an error that i try to overload this function `at`, which is correct :( But my mind can`t help me with a method to solve this error. Maybe you can give me an example or tell me what i can do in this case :)

```
template <class A,class B>

class BidirectionalMap
{
public:
    void insert(A a,B b)
    {
        m1.insert(std::pair<A,B> (a,b));
        m2.insert(std::pair<B,A> (b,a));
    }
    BidirectionalMap& operator =(BidirectionalMap &a)
    {
        m1=a.m1;
        m2=a.m2;
        return *this;
    }
    A& at(const A& a)
    {
        if(m1.find(a)!=m1.end()) return m1.at(a);
        else return m2.at(a);
    }
    const B& at(const A& b) const
    {
        return m1.at(b);
    }
    const A& at(const B& a) const
    {
        return m2.at(a);
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return m1.size();
    }
    int count(const A& a) const
    {
        return m1.count(a);
    }
    int count(const B& b) const
    {
        return m2.count(b);
    }
    B& operator[](const A& a)
    {
        return m1[a];
    }
    A& operator[](const B& b)
    {
        return m2[b];
    }
private:
    std::map<A,B> m1;
    std::map<B,A> m2;
};
```

And what if i cannot modify this sequence in main()?

```
  BidirectionalMap<int, int> f;
  f.insert(3, 18);
  f.insert(8, 2);
  f.insert(7, 5);
  f.insert(9, 1);
  const BidirectionalMap<int, int> cf = f;

  if( f.at(5) == 7 &&
      f.count(12) == 0 &&
      f.at(8) == 2)
  {
    yourMark = cf[18] + cf[9];
  }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen in this case?  There are two `map`s to look up in, which one do you want to look in?  Both?  Neither?

Comment: Try to use type traits: `std::enable_if` + `std::is_same`.

Comment: @Constructor a `template` function must have a specialization that it can be instantiated under or the program is ill formed, no diagnosis required.  So you cannot fully disable a method using SFINAE style techniques based on type parameters of the enclosing class (well, not by the standard: in practice, it works fine).

Comment: I want something like this `A& at(const A& a)
    {
        if(m1.find(a)!=m1.end()) return m1.at(a);
        else return m2.at(a);
    }` that when the two types are the same my function `at` behaves like normal.

Comment: You can do this using `enable_if` and `is_same`, but my opinion is that that will lead to unintuitive behavior, at least for some corner cases. A better solution would be to create two member functions, say `at_key` and `at_value`, that perform the lookup of their own respective maps.

Comment: @Constructor can you be more practical...I am new in this stuffs and it`s the first time i here about that `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`...

Comment: @Yakk This problem can be worked around by making one of two function members templated.

Comment: @Yakk Because it is a bidirectional map it will look in the first map to find the key.If it is found that will return m1.at other (the key it is in the second map) returns m2.at.

Comment: @Constructor the `template`d one **must** have a valid specialization.  You can hack it (so that it an unlikely specialization to occur), or you can ignore the standard's requirement that a valid specialization occur, but only one being `template`d does not help avoid the issue (that the OP wants 2(4) overloads in one case, and 1(2) in the other -- ()s for `const` ones)

Comment: @Yakk So you say that the code like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22385754/3043539) is not standard-compliant.

Comment: @Constructor yep!  A `template` function (and methods are functions) must have a valid specialization.  Failure means the program is ill-formed (no diagnostic required).  Lemme see if I can find that standards reference...

Comment: @Yakk You made me cry. :-)

Comment: @Yakk Can you look now to my post? What to do in this case when the main it`s given?

Comment: @Yakk And what about the code from the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22671379/3043539)?

Comment: @Constructor 14.6/8: If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. -- the same is true of some `...` `template` hacks in an adjacent sentence.  Your second link -- that function has valid specializations, so this restriction does not apply.  The member function answers, however, run into that rule I believe.

Comment: @lero Sorry, I am not going to read your homework assigner's mind.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for this reference. To be exact what do you think about [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22672882/3043539) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22671379/3043539)?

Comment: @Yakk Can you answer to my new question Yakk?

Comment: @lero no, if you have a second question, do not edit existing questions and add them.  Each SO question should be one question.  I am abusing this comment thread to point out how an alternative answer that Constructor had in mind to your problem isn't valid C++, my apologies for the noise.

Comment: @Constructor For every `template` function or method, is there a valid specialization?  If so, you are in the clear.  If not, the `template` function is ill-formed (no diagnistic required).  I see no `template` functions in the linked answer, just methods of `template` classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement `at` in a CRTP base class.

```
template<class D, class A, class B>
struct crtp_at {
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  const B& at(const A& b) const {
    return self()->m1.at(b);
  }
  const A& at(const B& a) const {
    return self()->m2.at(a);
  }
  B& at(const A& b) {
    return self()->m1.at(b);
  }
  A& at(const B& a) {
    return self()->m2.at(a);
  }
};
template<class D, class A>
struct crtp_at<D,A,A> {
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  A& at(const A& a) {
    if(self()->m1.find(a)!=self()->m1.end()) return self()->m1.at(a);
    else return self()->m2.at(a);
  }
  A const& at(const A& a) const {
    if(self()->m1.find(a)!=self()->m1.end()) return self()->m1.at(a);
    else return self()->m2.at(a);
  }
};
```

Then your class uses the above like:

```
template <class A,class B>
class BidirectionalMap:public crtp_at< BiDirectionalMap<A,B>, A, B >
{
  // rest of your code
};
```

however, I would advise actually **blocking** `at` in that case, and any other method where it is not clear which way you are going.

You should have methods that clearly go one way or the other in your code for cases like `short <-> double` anyhow.

Comment: `template <class A,class B> class BidirectionalMap:public crtp_at< BiDirectionalMap, A, B >`: here is an error as I can see. You have also forgot `self()` calls in the specialization of the `crtp` class template. And how do you access to the private members of `BidirectionalMap` class in members of the `crtp_at` template class?

Comment: @Constructor `friend` lets you bypass privacy restrictions if needed.

Comment: Yes, I know. :-) But I meant that there is no keyword `friend` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which is close to [**@Yakk**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk)'s [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23836117/3043539) but is based on [my old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22672882/3043539) to [the similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22671379/3043539):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class A, class B>
class BidirectionalMap;

template <class A, class B, bool = std::is_same<A, B>::value>
class BaseMap
{
public:

    BidirectionalMap<A, B>* self()
    {
        return static_cast<BidirectionalMap<A, B>*>(this);
    }

    const BidirectionalMap<A, B>* self() const
    {
        return static_cast<const BidirectionalMap<A, B>*>(this);
    }

    const A& at(const B& a)
    {
        return self()->m2.at(a);
    }

    const A& at(const B& a) const
    {
        return self()->m2.at(a);
    }

    // ...

};

template <class A, class B>
struct BaseMap<A, B, true> {};

template <class A, class B>
class BidirectionalMap : public BaseMap<A, B>
{
public:

    friend struct BaseMap<A, B>;

    const B& at(const A& b)
    {
        return m1.at(b);
    }

    const B& at(const A& b) const
    {
        return m1.at(b);
    }

    // ...

private:

    std::map<A, B> m1;
    std::map<B, A> m2;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

And after hard work this is my solution : A specialization for BidirectionalMap when the types are the same.Do you agree with it?

```
template<class A>

class BidirectionalMap<A,A>
{
public:
    void insert(A a,A b)
    {
        m1.insert(std::pair<A,A> (a,b));
        m1.insert(std::pair<A,A> (b,a));
    }
    BidirectionalMap& operator =(BidirectionalMap &a)
    {
        m1=a.m1;
        return *this;
    }
    const A& at(const A& a) const
    {
        return m1.at(a);
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return m1.size();
    }
    int count(const A& a) const
    {
        return m1.count(a);
    }
    A& operator[](A a)
    {
        return m1[a];
    }
    const A& operator[](A a) const
    {
        return m1[a];
    }
private:
    std::map<A,A> m1;
};
```

Comment: Why do you use only one `std::map` in this specialization? And why do you pass the arguments to some function members by value?

Comment: I use only one `std::map` because the key type coincide with key value type and as you see I put pairs in the map viceversa. At what function members do you exactly refer?

Comment: Oh, I inattentively read your code. I meant `void insert(A a,A b)`, `A& operator[](A a)` and `const A& operator[](A a) const`.

Comment: But i shouldn`t pass the arguments? I learned that `operator[]` should be passed like this `mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k)`...It`n not ok?

Comment: `const key_type& k`, not `key_type k`.